# Prevent div from jumping to a new row when min-width is not reached in html

Tags: html, css

I have been struggling lately trying to manage the divs I have in my web page.
Let's say I have four divs horizontally next to each other with a html code like this:

```html
<div style="float:left; width:24%; min-width:250px; height:90px; border: 2px solid #000;">
  div1
</div>
<div style="float:left; width:24%; min-width:20px; height:90px; border: 2px solid #000;">
  div2
</div>
<div style="float:left; width:24%; min-width:20px; height:90px; border: 2px solid #000;">
  div3
</div>
<div style="float:left; width:24%; min-width:20px; height:90px; border: 2px solid #000;">
  div4
</div>
```

The problem I have is when I resize my browser window the fourth div jumps under the row of divs leaving only three. (The div clearly wasn't anywhere near the minimum width of 20px.)

So my question is: Is there a way to prevent a div from jumping to the next row when minimum width has not been reached?

Thanks

**Edit:** I found out that it doesn't jump if I use percentages instead of pixels in the min-width property. This kinda solves my problem but I am still trying to get it working with px in the minimum width.

Answer (score 0):

```
could maybe use CSS media queries to change sizes depending on viewport,  

   @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
      .your_class_here {
        /* css style goes here; */
      }
    }
```

so at the width shown above do etc

Answer (score 0):

Add `box-sizing: border-box` to your CSS to include the border in the percentage width.

Otherwise, when the 2 x 2px for your borders becomes more than 1 percent of the screen or container width (which is the case as soon as the screen gets less than 400px wide), it will have the effect you describe.

Addition: Your first DIV has a min-width of 250px. This means, if 250px becomes less than 24%, this div will be (much) wider than 24% oc the overall width. Since the other DIVs still are 24% wide, the sum goes above 100% and the fourth DIV is pushed to the next row.

To avoid that, you should either assign smaller percentage values to the width of all DIVs or reduce the min-width of DIV1. In the example below, I did the first:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.x {
float:left; width:55%; min-width:250px; height:90px; border: 2px solid #000;
}
.y {
float:left; width:15%; min-width:20px; height:90px; border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="x" >
  div1
</div>
<div class="y">
  div2
</div>
<div class="y">
  div3
</div>
<div class="y">
  div4
</div>
```

Comment: I added it to the div "style" but nothing changed (will try it in a CSS). Should it be used by all four divs? Or is it something I'm maybe missing?

Comment: Yes, on all four. I would even add it for *everything*,  i.e. as a first CSS rule `* { box-sizing: border-box; }`

Comment: The divs still keep jumping when resizing the browser window. Could it be that I am missing something?

Comment: please note the addition to my answer